# With SCTP and SHA-1 the random parameters are exchanged in init and init ack. What is used as HMAC key?

Tags: dtls

- SCTP `INIT` has client random parameter.
- SCTP `INIT ACK` has server random parameter.

There are no shared keys.

Using SHA-1, what key does the client or server use when performing the HMAC calculation?

Does the sender use their own random parameter as the key?